# Usage of STAF/STAX in Automation

Tags: automation, automated-tests

I had been exploring on STAX/STAF past week.
It is used for test automation execution & is some what similar to Hudson.
I would like to know on which type of Tests it can be used. i.e functional tests, load tests etc., 
The functional automation tests are basically dependent on the framework i.e how they run, their return status on fail or pass are through the framework .
 How I can we integrate such with the Test Automation Framework like STAF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using STAF/STAX for over 4 years.

PROs:

- Open Source
- Cross-platform
- Concurrent execution
- Extensible (i.e. you can write your own services)
- Decent support from IBM through the STAF website

CONs:

- Sometimes buggy
- Difficult to diagnose problems
- Programming STAX scripts is awkward and ugly (i.e. scripting via XML tags and embedded jython)

I've found that STAF/STAX is useful for systems test.  It enables you, for example, to launch a server on one system and a client on another, then test their interaction.  It's also helpful if you need to test cross-platform, or for multiple language bindings.  I also like the fact that it can be used both in large, networked systems, as well as on an individual's desktop.

On the other hand, I would probably avoid using it for unit testing, or tests that are relatively simple and can be run on a single system.  I'd probably use a language specific unit framework for that.

Comment: Could me please let me know a detailed info

Answer (score 2):

STAF is not comparable to Hudson.

When I look at something like Hudson/Jenkins and Buildbot, I see GUI with emphasis on scheduling, viewing what's going on, what was done, and how it went.

STAF, on the other hand, is more like the plumbing for a QA framework over a distributed environment. It helps with launching processes, collecting logs, locking resources, etc.